# How to dynamic add image/imagebutton in android listview or gridview

Tags: android

I have a list of emotion icons(over 100 icons).
And I would like to display in a view that people can click it and toast what he is clicking.
[image: emotion icons]
Now, I have some confusing points:
1) What views should I use to include all this icons (GridView or ListView)?
2) How to dynamic add them or add them pro-grammatically? If I declare each one by one, I think it is no good. But any other ideas?
All the images icons is in drawable folder.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GridView` would be better in this case with a `PopupWindow`. Take a HashMap and store the name of the smiley as String and its Image as Resource Id.

eg:-

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new  HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put("smile", R.drawable.smile);
....
```

Now, Iterate through all the values(images) of HashMap and poplulate your GridView from the HashMap values(images).

And, inside Adapter class you can show images using `map.get(key);` to ImageView and set the Resource.

**UPDATE:**

I had just created a small demo for the same you can check it from [`here`](http://www.4shared.com/zip/eSXqzjp-/SmileyDemo.html).